# The following packages have been kept back. But the packages are not "phased"

Tags: 22.04

Since a few days I have this message whenever I try to upgrade packages:

> The following packages have been kept back:
> python3-software-properties software-properties-common 0 upgraded, 0
> newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.

According to several posts and articles on that matter, this problem is
related to an Ubuntu feature called "phasing update".
But in my case it turns out that the phased percentage of the kept back packages is zero:

```
sudo apt-cache policy software-properties-common 
software-properties-common:
  Installed: 0.99.22
  Candidate: 0.99.22.5
  Version table:
     0.99.22.5 500 (phased 0%)
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
 *** 0.99.22 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status


sudo apt-cache policy python3-software-properties
python3-software-properties:
  Installed: 0.99.22
  Candidate: 0.99.22.5
  Version table:
     0.99.22.5 500 (phased 0%)
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
 *** 0.99.22 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

So what's the problem here and how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0.99.22.5 500 (phased 0%)` still means phased. The presence of "(xx% phased)" indicates phasing.

Packages that are not phasing simply have blank space there: `0.99.22.5 500`            .

0% is normal under two circumstances:

- The package has just been introduced, and phasing has just begun.
- The package has been held after a problem was reported

Simply be patient for a few days. Don't try to force the upgrade (problems were reported!). Take no action at all. Just be patient, and it will resolve itself in a few days. Just wait and live your life normally.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So what should I do then ? Just wait ?